# php pagination for mysql result

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I know m asking it again maybe but i tried the questions available on pagination but couldnt understand dem properly ... need to know the way to paginate the results of the following query :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM info WHERE Cat1 = 'novel'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) die ("DAtabase acces faild bc : ". mysql_error());

echo " <ul class=listbkwide2>";

while($data = mysql_fetch_object($result))
{
$id = $data->id;
$name = $data->Bname ;
$continent = $data->Bauthor;

    echo "  <li class=bkd><a href='details.php?bid=$id'> 
         <img src='images/sbs/$name.jpg'  title='$name' alt=''>
      <ul class=showcasetitle> <span> $name </span> </ul>
       <p class=authname> By    <span> $continent</span></p>  
      ";
}
echo " </ul> ";
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
mysql_close();
```

Comment: Pagination is all in your query.  Consider how you can SAFELY accept request parameters to drive a LIMIT statement or an additional WHERE clause to control the scope of your returned recordset.

Answer (score 1):

You need to maintain the offset and then add a `LIMIT` clause to your query.

```
[LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}]
```

See [the doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html).